# get working php files via power shell

Tags: php, powershell, cmd

```
$out = shell_exec('powershell -command "& {Get-WmiObject win32_Process | where-object {($_.CommandLine -like \"*php*\") } | Select-Object ProcessId,CommandLine,\"MMxDelimiter\" | Format-List}" < NULL');

foreach (explode("MMxDelimiter :",$out) as $Row) {
    preg_match_all("/ProcessId[^:]+:[^0-9]+([0-9]+)[^a-z]*CommandLine[^:]+:(.+)/is",$Row,$OutPut);
    if (trim($OutPut[1][0]) != "") {
        $Files[] = array("ProcessId"=>$OutPut[1][0],"Command"=>preg_replace("/[\n][ ]+/","",$OutPut[2][0]));
    }
}
print_r($Files);
```

This code displays working php files via power shell it is working on win7 well but gives error on win server 2008 because of `< NULL` parameter.

Anyone can tell me how can i solve this issue

Comment: What error are you getting? (Don't describe it, add the actual error message to your question.) What's `< NULL` supposed to do? That doesn't mean anything in any version of PowerShell AFAIK, so I don't know how you have it working on Win7 unless you have some extension installed that can interpret that. Also, the escape character in PowerShell is the backtick (`), not backslash. So again, I don't know how this would be working on Win7 if you're escaping the double quotes with backslashes.

Comment: sorry for less information but describe in english is diffucult for me. the error message was "The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: You haven't explained what `< NULL` is supposed to do.

Comment: when i tried to execute without `< NULL` command prompt is waiting for press enter so my php script waiting until time out of php config

Comment: But that doesn't answer my question at all. I didn't ask "what happens if you try it without `< NULL`. I asked what is `< NULL` intended to *do*? You're passing that as a part of the command line to the shell, because it's within the single quotes, but **NULL** is not a keyword in either cmd or PowerShell. In fact, that explains why you're getting the error: You're telling cmd to execute powershell, and redirect input from a file called **NULL**. If there is no file by that name, you get exactly that error. So please explain what's the *purpose* of `< NULL`...not what happens without it.

Comment: I have used `< NULL` for to say command prompt don't wait for press enter key from keyboard return response directly. And thanks for your interest @AdiInbar

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. First of all, the null device is called **NUL** in cmd, not **NULL**. Second, AFAIK you can't redirect input from it. It's used to discard output redirected *to* it, with `> nul`. (No, I'm not suggesting that you do that, because it wouldn't serve any purpose. You're not trying to discard the output of the command.) Third, the command you're invoking doesn't require keyboard input in the first place.

Comment: Actually, my last comment made me realize what's probably going on. I think the problem is an unterminated string. I might have an answer for you in a couple of minutes...

Comment: Actually, I thought I had the answer, but there was a problem with it, so I deleted it. I'll come back this evening and post a corrected answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$out = shell_exec('powershell -command "& {Get-WmiObject win32_Process | where-object {($_.CommandLine -like \"*php*\") } | Select-Object ProcessId,CommandLine,\"MMxDelimiter\" | Format-List}" < '.__FILE__);

foreach (explode("MMxDelimiter :",$out) as $Row) {
    preg_match_all("/ProcessId[^:]+:[^0-9]+([0-9]+)[^a-z]*CommandLine[^:]+:(.+)/is",$Row,$OutPut);
    if (trim($OutPut[1][0]) != "") {
        $Files[] = array("ProcessId"=>$OutPut[1][0],"Command"=>preg_replace("/[\n][ ]+/","",$OutPut[2][0]));
    }
}
print_r($Files);
```

I have change `< NULL` with a real file path  `< __FILE__`  so it is not best solution but working!!!